# Rules for Haven't X Didn't

Tags: verbs, do-support

A friend of mine corrected this sentence...

> It's a sensation I didn't feel for ages

...to this one...

> It's a sensation I haven't feel for ages

He said this: "I think it is something like 'You do to an object' but 'You have something done to you'"

I know there are similar questions about this case in here, but I want to know if there are any rules and when/how to use them. How do I know when to use "didn't" or "haven't"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Didn't* is the simple past. You use it to describe a finished action that took place in the past.

> He **didn't** come to the mall with me yesterday.
>
> We **didn't** have a test on Monday.

*Haven't* is the present perfect. You use it to describe a continuous action that started in the past.

> We **haven't** been to the movie theater in a month.
>
> I **haven't** seen a solar eclipse since I was a child.

If you're currently feeling the sensation, or have felt that sensation recently, use *haven't*, which states that the past sensation has been **felt** today.

If the sensation never happened, or the sensation didn't happen for a certain duration in the past, use *didn't*, which states that the past sensation ended later in the past.